# JSON PUT returns statuscode 400

Tags: javascript, put, http-status-code-400

I HAVE to make a PUT request but no matter what I try I get the statuscode 400 which means "The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax." I can't figure out where the problem is. Here's the request part (using knockoutjs and dropwizard):

```
self.save = function(person){
    $.ajax("/testtest/hello-world?", {
        data: person,
        type: "PUT", 
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
};
```

It doesn't even reach the servlet and as far as I know the URL is correct.
Here's the request message:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -  -  [21/Jul/2014:08:02:45 +0000] "PUT /testtest/hello-world? HTTP/1.1" 400 - "http://localhost:8080/testtest/assets/index.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" 19
```

and the error message:

```
Unrecognized token 'name': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
```

Comment: Are there any other messages in the http response that gets returned?

Comment: @MattEllen I posted the whole error message.

Comment: The “error message” you’ve shown looks to be simply the corresponding line from the access log; check what the _error log_ has to say about the actual reason of the error.

Comment: @CBroe "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token" - but there is no arraylist involved...

Comment: I think you are misusing `ko.toJSON`, usually you'd just pass an object with observables to it and not to construct an object literal.

Comment: @m90 It still won't work with: 
data person,

I'll change it in the question too.

Comment: the data of ajax needs to be an object, something like `data: {p: person}`

Comment: @Rajesh then it says that p is supposed to be true, false, null or NaN

Comment: From official jquery ajax() doc: The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: add an error handler for ur ajax call, and see what is the issue

Comment: @Rajesh The errormessage says [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I changed it to

```
self.save = function(person){
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT", 
        data: person,
        url : "/testtest/hello-world?",
    });
};
```

Comment: hmm...didnt see that.. u had missed the url param to ajax call.

Comment: @Rajesh I had it like this before: 
    $.ajax("/testtest/hello-world?", {